# C++: subtract vectors

Tags: c++

I have two vectors. And I need to remove from vector1 what there is in vector2.

[EDIT: it isn't clear whether this means per-element subtraction as per the link below or set difference]

I use Visual Studio 2010.

There seems to be a method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.subtract.aspx

But it somehow doesn't work and even there is no code example.

Could you help me? If no standard method exists, maybe you could suggest how to organize it via loops? Thank you in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include <vector>;
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  vector<int> vector1;
  vector<int> vector2;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
vector1.push_back (i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    vector2.push_back (i);
  }

  myvector1 = Subtract(vector1, vector2); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The method you found is for .NET. That means that to use it with C++, you'd have to switch over to C++/CLI.

Comment: There seems to be a serious misunderstanding of what the function you linked does (2d vector substraction), and what you might want (set difference, or element-wise numeric substraction). Which is it?

Comment: @Timbo: "I need to remove from vector1 what there is in vector2". That's set difference, no misunderstanding.

Comment: @K-ballo you are probably right. However, it is kind of obvious that the linked method does not do that at all.

Comment: @Timbo: I guess the OP is just confused since _.Net Vector_ is a geometric vector and not a container, and he is clearly using containers...

Answer (score 28):

You should use `std::set_difference`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference

First you will need to `sort` your `vectors`, since `set_difference` operates on *sorted* ranges. That is, unless they are *sorted* already (like in your use case).

```
std::sort(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
std::sort(vector2.begin(), vector2.end());
```

Then you call it like this:

```
std::vector<int> difference;
std::set_difference(
    vector1.begin(), vector1.end(),
    vector2.begin(), vector2.end(),
    std::back_inserter( difference )
);
```

This will append to `difference` those elements found in `vector1` that are not found in `vector2`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a vector containing the indexes of the elements removed from `vector1`?

Answer (score 24):

`std::transform(vector1.begin(), vector1.end(), vector2.begin(), vector1.begin(), std::minus<int>())`

The 4th argument is the place of the result. It should work even if the size of vectors are different .

Comment: Just to clarify for someone who is doing a quick browse through: this does a per element subtraction not set difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `std::set_difference`, you can do this:

```
// substracts b<T> to a<T>
template <typename T>                                                                                            
void
substract_vector(std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)                                                     
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator       it = a.begin();
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it2 = b.begin();

    while (it != a.end())
    {
        while (it2 != b.end() && it != a.end())
        {
            if (*it == *it2)
            {
                it = a.erase(it);
                it2 = b.begin();
            }

            else
                ++it2;
        }
        if (it != a.end())
            ++it;

        it2 = b.begin();
    }
}
```

This will erase from `a` all values that are in `b`.

Good luck

Comment: Again this does not answer the question. This performs a set difference operation. The OP asked for element by element subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest switching to EigenVectors which has built-in arithmetic operations for vectors:

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html

So you can use operators like +,-,*,/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
  Matrix2d a;
  a << 1, 2,
       3, 4;
  MatrixXd b(2,2);
  b << 2, 3,
       1, 4;
  std::cout << "a + b =\n" << a + b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a - b =\n" << a - b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Doing a += b;" << std::endl;
  a += b;
  std::cout << "Now a =\n" << a << std::endl;
  Vector3d v(1,2,3);
  Vector3d w(1,0,0);
  std::cout << "-v + w - v =\n" << -v + w - v << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -9):

/*The simplest way*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int A,B,C;
 printf("enter the two numbers 1st 2nd=");
 scanf("%d",&A);
 scanf("%d",&B);
 C=A-B;
 printf("Result=");
 printf
}
```