# Comparing 2 vectors and removing elements from 2nd vector that are not found in the 1st - c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, find

I have 2 string vectors:

```cpp
vector < string > animals = {"cat", "dog", "pig", "tiger", "monkey", "lion"}
vector < string > someAnimals = {"dog", "mouse", "snake", "monkey", "cat"}
```

How can I compare these 2 vectors and remove elements in someAnimals vector("mouse" and "snake") that aren't found in the animals Vector?

Comment: Possibly a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175858/c-subtract-vectors

Comment: If I understand what you want, I think you should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483663/vector-intersection-in-c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: subtract vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175858/c-subtract-vectors)

Comment: Sample code [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: Please show the work you've already written so far, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results. You have to show your work first, and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your task and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: Have a look at [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed to sort the vectors then you can use the following approach as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector <std::string> animals = 
    {
        "cat", "dog", "pig", "tiger", "monkey", "lion"
    };

    std::vector <std::string> someAnimals = 
    {
        "dog", "mouse", "snake", "monkey", "cat"
    };

    auto not_present = [&animals]( const auto &s )
    {
        return 
        std::find( std::begin( animals ), std::end( animals ), s ) == std::end( animals );
    };

    someAnimals.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( someAnimals ),
                                       std::end( someAnimals ),
                                       not_present ), std::end( someAnimals ) );

    for ( const auto &s : someAnimals )
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
dog monkey cat
```

Otherwise you can use `std::binary_search` for the sorted vectors as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector <std::string> animals = 
    {
        "cat", "dog", "pig", "tiger", "monkey", "lion"
    };

    std::vector <std::string> someAnimals = 
    {
        "dog", "mouse", "snake", "monkey", "cat"
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( animals ), std::end( animals ) );
    std::sort( std::begin( someAnimals ), std::end( someAnimals ) );

    auto not_present = [&animals]( const auto &s )
    {
        return 
        not std::binary_search( std::begin( animals ), std::end( animals ), s );
    };

    someAnimals.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( someAnimals ),
                                       std::end( someAnimals ),
                                       not_present ), std::end( someAnimals ) );

    for ( const auto &s : someAnimals )
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```