# Is there any standard variadic function for erasing multiple elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Take this vector:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Let's say I want to remove some elements of a vector at some arbitrary indices: 0, 1, and 3. It's tedious to have to write something like this:

```
v.erase(v.begin());
v.erase(v.begin());
v.erase(v.begin() + 1);
```

Is there any standard function that takes in an arbitrary number of indices to erase from a vector? Something like this: `v.erase(0, 1, 3);`

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Nothing to prevent you from writing a `multi_erase` function that does this, perhaps taking [inspiration from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175858/c-subtract-vectors).

Comment: I would assume you get the indices (0, 1, 3) from somewhere, probably based on some condition. In this case, better alternative would be to use `erase_if`

Comment: If you sort a list of indices in reverse order you can then just iterate over the list and erase each index. Easy function to write. See the remove-erase idiom for efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

There's nothing that deals with indices. There's also nothing that deals with arbitrary elements.

But you can erase multiple items that form a contiguous range at once. So you can coalesce your first two calls to `erase` into one (and probably about double the speed in the process).

```cpp
// erase the first two elements
v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to erase first three element so for this you can run.

```
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    v.erase(v.begin(),v.begin()+3);
```

or,

```
v.erase(v.begin(),v.end()-2);
```